# Eclipse IDE content assist for custom XMLs

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, richfaces

How can I activate content assist in Eclipse Indingo for Richfaces component tags, without instaling the JBoss Tools?

My Eclipse version just help with the default components of JSF.

Comment: What's wrong with installing JBoss Tools? There are as far as I know no other plugins which support RichFaces autocompletion.

Comment: Jboss Indigo is currently beta. At enterprise we must to use IBM RSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **JSF Project Facet** to your project. (You can *Disable Library Configuration* and still benefit from Richfaces code completion)

More info here:

[Eclipse Help - Project Facet](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/cfacets.html)

[JSF Project Facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533341/add-jsf-project-facet-in-eclipse-why-need-it)

Comment: Thanks Wojetk! It's so simple! And I thought my project already had this JSF Facet.